# How to configure my favorite editor in ModelSim?

Tags: vhdl, software

I want to set up my favorite editor in ModelSim. The default behavior is that ModelSim uses its own internal editor, which I don't like.

I've Googled and I've searched the ModelSim User Manual. I figured out that:

- If you set the `EDITOR` environment variable, the TCL `edit` command will use your editor.
- You can configure the project to execute a custom command when you double-click a file (I've set this custom command to `edit %f` which opens the file with my editor.

Still, when I double-click a compile error, the default (built-in) editor is opened. This is not what I want.

Is there a global setting so that the internal editor is not used, but my own editor is?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Brian I did this on Linux.

Comment: Have you asked Mentor?

Comment: I haven't. I'm not a direct Mentor customer, so they won't let me in their support system. I'm trying to go through Altera who ships ModelSim too.

Comment: This isn't even remotely related to this forum.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith: Lots of people use ModelSim for VHDL and Verilog work.

Comment: Sure, but this is a question unrelated to digital electronic design. It's asking how to use a specific piece of software, to configure it for a user preference. It has nothing to do with electronics or engineering. It's a software support question.

Comment: @AndrewKohlsmith: "It has nothing to do with electronics or engineering." - That would be true if ModelSim were accounting software or something that is *actually* unrelated to electronics or engineering.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Even once you get it setup, it won't truly be integrated with Modelsim where it will highlight lines with warnings or errors, or anything like that.  It won't behave like an IDE.

I've always just used my editor (gvim) standalone and then ran Modelsim separately.

Answer (score 3):

For those using the external_editor tcl script and get in trouble trying to restore functionality to ModelSim:

Open up *regedit*, go to:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Model Technology Incorporated\ModelSim
```

There you will find the PrefSource key. Delete the altEditor value, and that will fix your ModelSim issues.

Comment: I didn't find PrefSource key there... (PrefDefault PrefWave is present). What do you Mean by altEditor value?
My .vhdl files are getting open in Notepad++ and I want it to get opened inside dfault Modelsim editor only. Plz help as I already tried default open with option which is opening New Modelsim exe for each vhd file iwant to open

Comment: In addition to deleting the altEditior value from HKEY_CURRENT_USER, one must delete it from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as well to revert back the changes.

Comment: Or, more simply run in modelsim the command `unset PrefSource(altEditor)`

Answer (score 2):

Put this in a tcl file somewhere:

```
proc external_editor {filename linenumber} {
 exec "youreditor" $linenumber $filename &   # edit as required
}
set PrefSource(altEditor) external_editor
```

Comment: Didn't work. Do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: @Philippe - What did you try? What was the error message?

Comment: I tried executing the Tcl command that Anon gave. No error messages, but no different default editor. It would be great so see some documentation on this "PrefSource" thing that Anon uses.

Answer (score 2):

Anon's answer got me where I was going, but I thought I'd add a specific example. I use Arch linux and GVim.

This line only needs to be ran once. I ran it directly in Modelsim's terminal.

```
set PrefSource(altEditor) external_editor
```

This is the actual function I used

```
proc external_editor {filename linenumber} {
    exec gvim +$linenumber $filename &
}
```

However, the external_editor proc still needs to be added to Modelsim. As a one off, you can actually just drop the function into the terminal, but I created a modelsim.tcl file within my home directory.

In that I linked to the external_editor.tcl file elsewhere.

```
source /opt/altera/15.1/modelsim_ase/tcl/custom_scripts/external_editor.tcl
```

I suspect there is any number of ways to permanently load the external editor proc, but this is what I did.

As a side note, I would have placed this as a comment under Anon's answer, but I don't have enough reputation as I just created my account.

Comment: Caution: Anyone before trying the things of this answer, be aware that its going to affect registry of pc. For reverting back to default modelsim functionality, simple uninstall & reinstall won't work. You would have to edit the registry. [ follow @dolk's answer for that].

Comment: @SourabhTapas you can run `unset PrefSource(altEditor)` in ModelSim to clear the setting. No need to resort to registry editing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options you may use:

- `PrefSource(altEditor)`: this replaces the internal editor when double-clicking etc., i.e. when normally the internal editor would be shown.
- `PrefMain(Editor)`: this sets the external editor that can be launched from some menus. It doesn't support the `linenumber` argument AFAICT.

For my setup I followed these steps (to eventually launch [geany](https://www.geany.org) as the editor):

1. To make questasim load a separate settings file at startup, set the `MODELSIM_TCL` environment variable to point to the path of the respective file, e.g.:

   ```
   export MODELSIM_TCL="$HOME/.mentor/perf.tcl"
   ```

   Alternatively, you can just put the following into `~/modelsim.tcl` AFAIK.
2. Add this to the settings file:

   ```
   # Launch custom command as external editor:
   proc external_editor {filename} {
     exec geany "$filename" &
   }
   set PrefMain(Editor) external_editor

   # Replace the internal editor:
   proc external_editor_ln {filename linenumber} {
    exec geany "$filename:$linenumber" &
    return
   }
   set PrefSource(altEditor) external_editor_ln

   # Fix default viewers
   set PrefMain(pdfViewer) xdg-open
   set PrefMain(htmlViewer) xdg-open
   ```

   Note the extra return startment in `external_editor_ln` that prohibits the function to return a value, which would create an error output `# invalid command name "0"` (where `0` is the return value).
   The last two statements are a "bonus" that for example fix launching documentation if you don't have `acroread` installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to use ModelSim in command-line

Creat project using `vlib` and `vmap` 
Compile Verilog using `vlog`
Compile VHDL using `vcom`
view simulation using `vsim <top module name>`
during simulation : `run` `step`

Details in User Manual :

https://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hadi/teaching/cs3220/doc/modelsim/ModelSim_Users_Manual_v10.1c.pdf

Useful Tutorial :

http://www.tkt.cs.tut.fi/tools/public/tutorials/mentor/modelsim/getting_started/gsms.html

Answer (score 0):

The configuration setting you are looking for can be managed in one of several ways. From what I have read, the two most common methods are by accessing either the files `pref.tcl` and `modelsim.tcl`. More info can be had if you search on either of those file names in a ModelSim "[user guide](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/131619-modelsim-user)" or "[quick guide](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Edon/coe1502/Reference/vsim_quickref.pdf)". According to the [quick guide](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/%7Edon/coe1502/Reference/vsim_quickref.pdf) entry,

#### pref.tcl

- Found at `/<install_dir>/modeltech/tcl/vsim/pref.tcl`
- Will always load at ModelSim launch.

#### modelsim.tcl

- Loads the first file found among the following:

  1. `$MODELSIM_TCL` if the environment variable is defined and the file exists.
  2. `./modelsim.tcl`, i.e. a file named as such in the current directory.
  3. `$HOME/modelsim.tcl`, again if the environment variable is defined.

This is where the previous responses come into play. In either of the locations listed above, you can drop in your **Tcl** function. I lifted the implementation from the previous posts by [Anon](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/10393/anon), [J D R](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/108188/j-d-r), [stefanct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/23934/stefanct), but improved upon the usage of the `exec` command based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632326/tcl-exec-to-open-a-program-with-agruments). Certainly modifications can be made, but here's my function written specifically for Notepad++. Notice that the `notepad++` argument and the `"-n..."` tacked onto the `linenumber` parameter are specific to Notepad++.

```
        proc external_editor {filename linenumber} {
            exec {*}[auto_execok start] notepad++ $filename "-n$linenumber"
            return
        }

        set PrefSource(altEditor) external_editor
```

With this this code dropped into `pref.tcl` or `modelsim.tcl`, if you double-click in the ModelSim terminal on a line with with compilation errors, ModelSim should launch the editor of your choice to the offending line of code.

---

NOTE: The reference guides mentioned above seem to not be readily available directly from Mentor Graphics, which is a Siemens property at the time of post. Most common source seems to be universities.

Answer (score -3):

Change the default editor for .v or .vhd files in Windows. Choose "Open As..." and the check the checkbox to make the selected app default.

Comment: How is this going to make Modelsim use another editor?

Comment: It's not helping!