# Set alternative editor for ModelSim

Tags: linux, modelsim

I want to set an alternative editor in ModelSim. I tried [How to configure my favorite editor in ModelSim?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17359/how-to-configure-my-favorite-editor-in-modelsim) and after I set the altEditor I get "unknown command external_editor". Unfortunately my reputation is too low to comment on that question.

I also tried setting PrefSource(Editor) and specify the one I am using. This had no effect at all.

I am on Linux btw and want to use kate as an editor.

Comment: why would you want to comment on the other question?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the editor with an absolute path.

Open a console, and use the "which" command to get the complete path to the binary of your editor.

For my computer and kate, it looks like this:

```
> which kate   
> /opt/kde3/bin/kate
```

Use that in the spot where the other question (and answers) say to enter the name of your editor.

Comment: No, the same thing. Tried to edit it in the file and the command.

Comment: Did you use my path, or did you use "which" on your computer?

Comment: I used my path which is /usr/bin/kate

Comment: I realized that by specifying kate I can now open the file, if I select "Open in external editor" after I right-clicked inside ModelSim's editor. What I want is, that it opens the file in the external editor every time